# android how to disable popup longpress softkeyboard

Tags: android, popup, android-softkeyboard, long-press

I am building a softkeyboard based on the android softkeyboard sample code, and i don't want to show a popup every time a key is longpressed. Like Below [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed86r.png]

Is there anyone who can tell me where i can find this in the softkeyboard samplecode, or how to disable it.

here is a link to the samplecode https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard?autodive=0%2F

Thanks!!

Comment: if not code atleast add link to that sample code.

Comment: @VivekMishra I added the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is rater simple, after looking around in the keyboardview.java file i found the setPreviewEnabled function. in the latinkeybaordview add setpreviewenabled(false) to the latinkeyboardview fucnction like this.

```
 public LatinKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setPreviewEnabled(false);
}
```